# Should I better use VARCHAR(3) or BIGINT() for my primary key with PostgreSQL?

Tags: database, postgresql

I'm seeding a big main table and generating smaller tables from some columns. These smaller tables are linked to the big one with foreign keys.

The small tables have a 2~3 characters unique code for each entry, so using an bigint `id` to store them seems superfluous to me. Also, I don't need auto-incrementation.

In such case, should I set the code of type varchar(3) as my primary key ? Or is bigint always better for performances ?

Comment: If the primary key really contains "characters" (e.g. `abc`) then you have no choice other than `varchar`. If those are really only (small) numbers, then maybe use `smallint` - but honestly it doesn't really matter that much. What do you consider "big" here?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks for your answer. I could use `smallint` indeed, would it improve performances over `bigint` ? I'm actually wondering about performances of queries in the main table if I have 'abc' stored in the foreign keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Performance won't matter much in this case, and a few bytes of storage more or less won't either.

You should choose the primary key that is most practical. If there is a natural three-character unique identifier, and you are sure that the identifier will never change for an existing table row, then there is no problem with using `varchar(3)` as a primary key for a table.

Note that there are people who think that you should *always* use a numeric artificial primary key. These people will probably disagree, and I am not willing to start a holy war here. The only convincing argument for this stance that I have heard is that there are ORMs and other abstraction layers that cannot work with anything but a numerical primary key. But if you are not hobbled by such a tool, you need not worry.